# Bot framework not response when sending message by ReplyToActivityAsync

Tags: botframework

Below section usually works well, but sometimes it will not response, the message is from Microsoft Teams. i'm sure that the endpoint has received the message, but can not send the message out.

```
     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{   
  //show typing
  var reply = activity.CreateReply(String.Empty);
  reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
  ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
  await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
...
}
```

Comment: Try adding a call to MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl); before ReplyToActivityAsync

Comment: I tried this, but can not work. not sure why somtimes the address 'smba.trafficmanager.net' is not accessable, need to wait a while, and reboot the teams sometimes can help to re-access this address.